# should preloaded images with javascript specify its size on html code?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I know that when loading images with html, the image tag should always specify
the height and width of the image to prevent problems and to improve the loading of the image. (I know that some developers think different, but this is not the post to argue about that)

Currently I'm pre-loading some images with javascript:

```
var flag_fr_path=main_deep+'-images/flag_french.jpg'
var flag_fr_image= new Image(45,30);
flag_fr_image.src = flag_fr_path;
```

and then, I'm using them on my html code:

`<img src="'+flag_es_path+'"></img>`

My question is if the html tag should also specify the size of the image to make the browser to save its space? Or the fact of having specify the size in the javascript code makes the browser know everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simply: yes. The image isn't guaranteed to load and in fact there's no guarantee the user has javascript enabled.

In these cases, it's clearly better to have the size of the element specified in the HTML.

Comment: If the user don't have JS enabled there is no need to specify the size cause element's won't load at all

Comment: Is the `img` tag loaded with javascript? I didn't get that from the question (although upon closer reading, I think that might be what rsm meant). If so, that is a good point and I'm not sure it makes any difference...so I'd do it anyway.

Comment: Actually the `img` tag is on a javascript code because it is the header of my website. But I didn't thought on that when I posted the question, both of you have reason!